# Action Cable Allowed Request Origins regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, actioncable

I am working with Rails 5 and Action Cable, trying to configure the allowed request origins option.  I can't quite figure out how to generate the appropriate regex for what I need:

```
http://*.ENV["APP_HOSTNAME"]:3000
```

Basically, I need to be able to provide a rails environment variable to specify the host and have wildcard subdomains.  I've tried a variety of expressions and can't quite get it.  Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [
  %r{\Ahttps?://[^./]+\.#{ ENV['APP_HOSTNAME'].gsub('.', '\.') }:3000\z},
  %r{\Ahttps?://[^./]+\.#{ ENV['APP_HOSTNAME'].gsub('.', '\.') }:3000/}
]
```

This will allow only for level 1 subdomains. I'm not 100% sure second regexp is needed.